# Wireless Emergency Alerts not working on identical Galaxy S5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, alerts

My wife and I have identical Galaxy S5 phones (SM-G900A) on an AT&T family plan. She has received numerous WEAs (weather alerts, amber alerts) in the year we've had them, but I have not received a single one. The only thing different is that she's stayed on Jellybean (I think) while I've upgraded through Kitkat and then on to Lollipop. However, the menu options, and current settings  are the same. I've tried the disabling and re-enabling but won't know until the next alert comes along.

Two part question then:

1. Can I get a test alert sent to my phone? If so, how?
2. Is there something about Lollipop that affects WEAs?

(WEAs in US/SoCalifornia)